# Combining elements within a 2d array python 3.x

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

i have this 2d array, where each array is made up of 4 lots of 4 hex values:

list1=[['74 68 61 74', '73 20 6D 79', '20 6B 75 6E', '67 20 66 75'], ['C2 5B FC F1', 'B1 7B 91 88', '91 10 E4 E6', 'F6 30 82 93']]

And I would like to firstly split the array into multiple 1d arrays then combine the array into multiple single elements rather than each element having 4 values, like follows:

list2=[74, 68, 61, 74, 73, 20, 6D, 79, 20, 6B, 75, 6E, 67, 20, 66, 75]

list 3=[C2, 5B, FC, F1, B1, 7B, 91, 88, 91, 10, E4, E6, F6, 30, 82, 93]

Please let me know how this can be done. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you essentially want to do is "flatten" the inner lists.  There are several approaches to this.  The example below borrows from [here](https://stackabuse.com/python-how-to-flatten-list-of-lists/).  Realize that the values in your lists are just strings (even though they could represent hex values) so you need to treat them like strings when splitting them up.

```
In [25]: list1                                                                    
Out[25]: 
[['74 68 61 74', '73 20 6D 79', '20 6B 75 6E', '67 20 66 75'],
 ['C2 5B FC F1', 'B1 7B 91 88', '91 10 E4 E6', 'F6 30 82 93']]

In [26]: list2 = [t for sublist in list1[0] for t in sublist.split(' ')]          

In [27]: list3 = [t for sublist in list1[1] for t in sublist.split(' ')]          

In [28]: list2                                                                    
Out[28]: 
['74',
 '68',
 '61',
 '74',
 '73',
 '20',
 '6D',
 '79',
 '20',
 '6B',
 '75',
 '6E',
 '67',
 '20',
 '66',
 '75']

In [29]: list3                                                                    
Out[29]: 
['C2',
 '5B',
 'FC',
 'F1',
 'B1',
 '7B',
 '91',
 '88',
 '91',
 '10',
 'E4',
 'E6',
 'F6',
 '30',
 '82',
 '93']

In [30]:
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually had around 10 other lists within the array and this has made it possible for me to use each list.